# So when do I get my commit back? (Area51)

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase, uncommit

I committed to an Area51 site, which has since exited private beta and gone into Public Beta.

There is a fourth site that I would have very, very, very much have liked to have been able to support; now that one of my committed sites has gone into Public Beta (meaning, I could use it even if I had not ever committed to it in the first place), is there any way I can get my commit back to use to support the fourth site I was going to support?  Or do I have to wait until the site exits Public Beta?

Comment: No refund! What do you think, what this is? The Salvation Army?

Comment: I think the commits have to be manually "refunded" at the moment. I got mine back from "Web Applications" and "Gaming" at the same time despite the sites going into beta a week apart.

Comment: @ChrisF is that still true (manual "refunds" of commit tokens)? I've fulfilled what I understand to be my commitment to Network Engineering, but I'm not seeing that reflected on my Area51 profile. Any suggestions on how to resolve this apparent conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked [the area 51 /faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) ? You should.

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta (up to 90 days).

We're being a bit coy about "few" here because I don't want people to start gaming it. But I will tell you that:

1. It's highly advisable to participate in the private beta
2. The earliest you can have your commitment fulfilled is the 2nd day of public beta.

Comment: I got the Beta badge and 300 rep :(  I was one of the more active users the first few days, but when the questions stopped coming it became hard to contribute.  If that's not enough, can I still redeem myself in public beta?

Answer (score -1):

<del>You don't get your commit slot back until the public beta is over.</del>

*I'll keep this answer here because of the comments.*

Comment: You get it back when you fulfilled the requirements as stated in Juan's comment, which may or may not be at the end of the *private* beta. No public beta is over so far and yet many have gotten their token back already

Comment: not correct, FYI

Comment: @TobiasKienzler where is Juan's comment you refer to above? I've fulfilled what I understand to be my commitment to Network Engineering, but I'm not seeing that reflected on my Area51 profile. Any suggestions on how to resolve this apparent conflict?

Comment: @CopyrightX [That](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57993/so-when-do-i-get-my-commit-back-area51/58019?noredirect=1#comment137626_58019) is almost three years old, back when linking to other comments wasn't trivial (to me at least). The comment I was referring to seems to have been deleted meanwhile. Maybe you ask (or search) a new question on these requirements. Though [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58066/146482) sounds like whatever you consider a fulfilled commitment may still be not "enough". Or you'll simply have to wait a few days for the system to catch up